# I am having different value from compiler and calculator

Tags: java

I was writing a code (I knew the output,In **Java**) , after compiling it giving the input i got a weird value.

*Code Snippet* -

```
    long a,b,c;
    a=-245436499;
    b=992;
    c=(a+b);
    System.out.print(c%b);
```

And the *Output* it gave me was

```
-819
```

But when i calculated it on calculator, it was

```
173 \\why?
```

**Proof:**
 [Calculators output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QaCV5.png)
[Compiler's output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgXPV.png)

Comment: You're doing something wrong on your calculator.

Comment: Agree with @Kon What do you think that `c%b` does?

Comment: Check the image links ,please.

Comment: @JorgeCampos `c%b` gives the reminder of the Division between c and b

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways of calculating modulo of a negative number:

1. Java (as per the JLS) uses the "preserve sign" method; ie if the first operand is negative, non-zero results are negative
2. Results are (made) positive by adding (if necessary) the second operand to the result of method 1

Your calculator clearly uses method 2 (`-819 + 992 = 173`)

Comment: Don't you think it violates the normal calculation methodologies ?

Comment: @nam What's "abnormal" here? Is it "abnormal" that `√-1` is `i` or that `e^-iπ` is `-1`?